# Can an Italian type D visa be used to enter Mexico?

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration, italy, mexico, tunisian-citizens

My wife came to Italy from Tunisia through a family reunification visa that is valid until March 2018. We are planning to go for a honeymoon trip to Cancun, Mexico.

Can she enter Mexico with the Italian D multi-entry visa?

Is she allowed to fly directly from Italy, or does she have to travel there from the country where the visa was issued (Tunisia)?

I was told that she needs a residence permit to travel from Italy to any other country. She didn’t get the residence permit yet, it’s already in process and I have just got a receipt. A national visa from a Schengen country is normally considered as a Schengen visa even if the word Schengen is not written on the visa.

Comment: This duplicates your earlier question, which I've voted to reopen. You might want to delete one. Thanks.

Comment: "I was told that she needs a residence permit to travel from Italy to any other country": by whom?

Comment: has a multiple entry visa valid for litalia expires in March

Comment: Do you want to return to Italy before of after the visa expires?

Comment: Before, they make me enter Mexico with a national Italian visa for a two week honeymoon?a Mexican authorities accept passengers with a valid Italian visa multi-entry?

Comment: Are you asking whether you can re-enter Italy when you return?  Or whether you can enter Mexico with that visa?

Comment: enter Mexico with the Italian visa multi-entry

Answer (score 6):

> Can she enter Mexico with the Italian D multi-entry visa?

**Yes She can visit Mexico without a visa** while her Schengen visa is still valid.

> With the purpose of facilitating and promoting travel to Mexico, effective May 2016 all those foreign nationals, regardless of their nationality, visiting Mexico for tourism, business or transit are NOT required to obtain a Mexican visa IF they hold a valid (non-expired) Visa or Permanent Residence of any of this countries: United States of America, Canada, Japan, United Kingdom or Schengen area (European Union).

**[Source](https://consulmex2.sre.gob.mx/sanfrancisco/index.php/visas-traveling-to-mexico)**

This is also suggested by [Timatic](https://www.emirates.com/english/before-you-fly/visa-passport-information/find-visa-requirements-results.aspx?NC=TN&NV=Tunisia&DC=MX&DV=Mexico&h=303a9de9e748cadd18b24ecb6d4622c271ea8e24) as noted by @ugoren

Comment: [A Timatic query](https://www.emirates.com/english/before-you-fly/visa-passport-information/find-visa-requirements-results.aspx?NC=TN&NV=Tunisia&DC=MX&DV=Mexico&h=303a9de9e748cadd18b24ecb6d4622c271ea8e24) confirms this. Although less authoritative than the Mexican government, this is what the airline checks prior to boarding, which makes it quite important.

Comment: I checked multiple consulates of Mexico around the world, and the only ones with that note are the ones in the US. Both, [Rome embassy](https://embamex.sre.gob.mx/italia/index.php/es/seccion-consular/172-visa-de-turista) and [Milan consulate](https://consulmex.sre.gob.mx/milan/index.php/servicios-consulares/documentacion-a-extranjeros/5) says that the only valid visa is the one from USA. Maybe the best thing to do would be to call one of the consulates to ask.

Comment: It is possible that those were not promptly updated with the new information? I think Timatic also ads some reassurance to this answer’s assessment however you’re right there is nothing better than asking the directly related consulate

Answer (score 2):

Since people from Tunisia need visa to enter Mexico the Italian visa is not valid for Tunisian citizens trying to enter to Mexico.

According to the Mexican Foreign Affairs office she would be able to enter without Mexican visa only if one of the following is true:

a) Holds a permanent residence of one of the following countries: Canada, USA, Japan, UK or any Schengen Area country

b) She has a valid American Visa

So, those are your only options if she wants to visit Mexico. I don't know if she is Italian resident or not; or if she holds an US visa; other than that she needs to apply for a Mexican visa.

I've been checking after the other answer was added and Mexican websites seem to differ according to which dependency you check. All national institutes seem to agree that only USA visas would be accepted, data seems to be outdated if we take in count the date the other answer states.

On Mexican consulates websites like the ones in San Francisco, New York and South Africa mention what the other answer says, that a valid visa from USA, Schecngen Area countries, Canada, UK and Japan is valid in Mexico. But others like the ones in Madrid, Milan and Roma only say that USA visa is valid.

Best thing would be to call the Mexican consulate in Italy and ask them, since they would have the real data.

**Sources:** [Tourism Secretary Visa page (Spanish)](http://www.sectur.gob.mx/guia-de-viaje/visa/). [Mexican Migration Institute: Countries that need visa to enter Mexico (Spanish)](http://www.inm.gob.mx/gobmx/word/index.php/paises-requieren-visa-para-mexico/)

Comment: Perhaps you should link to your source since it disagrees with the other answer.  The other answer links to an official source, so it seems more credible at the moment.

Comment: Most of the official Mexican websites are available only in Spanish, that's why I didn't include them.

Comment: I don't trust the official Mexican websites, particularly immigration.  I've just been into Mexico immigration and their staff told me their data is incorrect or out-of-date and not to trust any of it.